# how to avoid/remove invalidcastexception

Tags: vb.net, ssis

Within a SSIS 05 (VB.NET) script, an interesting exception occured. The development environment does not show any errors concerning the script.

Following error message is shown within the script component in the ETL process.

```
Unable To Cast COM Object Of Type 'System.__ComObject' To Class Type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
```

A connection manager is in use.

```
Dim connMgr As IDTSConnectionManager90
```

Here the applied `CType` command.

> Public Overrides Sub AcquireConnections(ByVal Transaction As Object)
>
> ```
>       connMgr = Me.Connections.Connection
>       sqlConn = CType(connMgr.AcquireConnection(Nothing), SqlConnection)
>
> End Sub
> ```

Any experience how to avoid this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

btw The 2012 version (in C#) works without troubles. The 2005 version was manually downgraded/rewritten.

```
public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
{
    connMgr = this.Connections.Connection;
    sqlConn = (SqlConnection)connMgr.AcquireConnection(null);
}
```

Addendum:
That does not work.

> sqlConn = New SqlConnection(connMgr.ConnectionString)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast problem was an issue even without a cast (see snippet above with new keyword).

Hence, statements were rewritten.
The main point --- no problem furthermore concerning the old issue.

```
oleDbConn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connMgr.ConnectionString)
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of, if you are using explicit transactions, this will not enlist in the existing connection manager's transaction